# Stylelint wont mark errors in VSCode

Tags: css, node.js, visual-studio-code, sass, stylelint

VScode doesn't show me any stylint errors.

package.json:

```
    ...
    "postcss": "^8.4.12",
    "postcss-scss": "^4.0.3",
    "stylelint": "^14.7.1",
    "stylelint-config-sass-guidelines": "^9.0.1",
```

.stylelintrc.json:

```
{
    "extends": "stylelint-config-sass-guidelines",
    "files": ["**/*.scss"],
    "customSyntax": "postcss-scss",
    "rules": {
        "color-named": "always-where-possible",
        "max-nesting-depth": 5,
        "selector-max-compound-selectors": 6,
        "selector-no-qualifying-type": [
            true,
            {
                "ignore": ["attribute", "class", "id"]
            }
        ],
        "selector-max-id": 1,
        "no-extra-semicolons": true
    }    
}
```

vscode settings.json

```
    ...
    "stylelint.enable": true,
    "css.validate": false,
    "scss.validate": false,
    "less.validate": false,
```

Thats all i have configured. Im on vscodestylelint 1.2.2.
Stylelint it self works in console just fine, vscode just won't show any errors.

Answer (score 13):

[Like Stylelint itself](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/get-started), the [Stylelint VS Code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stylelint.vscode-stylelint) [only lints CSS by default](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stylelint.vscode-stylelint#only-css-and-postcss-are-validated-by-default). You must configure the extension to lint other languages like SCSS using the [`stylelint.validate` property](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stylelint.vscode-stylelint#stylelint.validate):

```
// vscode settings.json
...
"css.validate": false,
"scss.validate": false,
"stylelint.validate": ["css", "scss"],
```

This will turn off VS Code's built-in validator for CSS and SCSS, and then turn on Stylelint for them.

Comment: this does not help in my case

Comment: it helped in my case

Comment: it helped me too

Answer (score 7):

In my case this didn't work because I also had

```
"stylelint.config": {},
```

in settings.json, and once I changed it to

```
"stylelint.config": null,
```

it started working

Comment: Thank you! Removing the line entirely also worked for me. There's a link in the Stylelint extension settings under "Config" named "Edit in settings.json" which appears to create this, which disables linting by default, and overrides settings in `.stylelintrc`

Answer (score 1):

The fix for me was to include `postcss` as a value for stylelint to validate, since I'm using `postcss`. I thought just including the `[ "css", "scss" ],` values would work since those are the file extensions I'm using but
I guess it's the technology being used?

Anyway in VS Code settings add/edit the `stylelint.validate` option to:

```
"stylelint.validate": [ "css", "scss", "postcss" ],
```